# Passing data from blade to route

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to list articles from database then show details of the article when the user clicks on it.
How can I pass the article id or name to the route/controller to display the details? I tried butting the id in the href but I don't know how to handle it from routes!

this is the articles list:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="#">{{$article->name}}</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View file for listing all the articles:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}">{{$article->name}}</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
```

**ArticlesController.php**

```
/**
 * Show the article of the given id.
 *
 * @param int $id The id of the article
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<h3>{{ $article->name }}</h3>

<p>{{ $article->body }}</p>
```

Comment: had to remove the $ from compact('$article').
and it worked as a charm :)
Thank you very much 
have a nice day

Comment: Glad that it worked out. Kindly accept the answer so that it can be helpful for other users as well..

Comment: look like OP is new for such thing, I vote up for descriptive answer.

Comment: I have no idea how to accept the answer.
sorry but I'm still new to all this :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`route()`](https://github.com/pmatseykanets/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L591) you can pass parameters in second argument

```php
@foreach ($articles as $article)
     <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="{{ route('article.show', [$article->id]) }}">{{ $article->name }}</a>
                             ^^^ or whatever is the name of your route
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Naturally this assumes you have your route defined in `app\Http\routes.php`. For example

```php
Route::get('/articles/{id}', ['as' => 'article.show', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@show']);
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`url()`](https://github.com/pmatseykanets/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L707)

```php
@foreach ($articles as $article)
     <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="{{ url('/articles', [$article->id] }}">{{ $article->name }}</a>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i tried this and it gives me (Route [article.show] not defined.)

Comment: That's because you naturally need to define this route in `routes.php`